# What is the difference between expo and react native app developing?

Tags: react-native, expo

I am going to develop react native app using **Expo** but I don't have idea which one is best? Please suggest me any idea?

Actually I am using **Expo**. Which is best **Expo** or normal **Android** or **Xcode** development?

Answer (score 3):

When you write code in Expo (abbr. XDE), you write React Native code. Expo has two main pieces:

1) `XDE`: a developer tool for creating projects, viewing logs, opening on your device, publishing, etc.

2) The `Expo client`: an app on your phone that lets you open your projects while you're working on them, without needing to go through XCode or Android Studio, and also lets other people view them too!

**But** ...

> With most apps in React Native, you end up needing to utilise several
>   third party native libraries, which Expo doesn’t current support
>   outside of their built in APIs. There are a lot of things that can be
>   done in JS only, but I’ve always ended up running into a need for
>   native libraries with every React Native project I’ve worked on
>   (several production apps). That being said, Expo does support
>   “detaching” your app from Expo, which will allow you to carry on with
>   a standard free standing React Native app.

Expo has some advantages over using normal Xcode/Studio like expo client, but it also has its cons when it comes to large scale applications . You can choose based on your needs.

If you’re just getting started and you need to get off the ground quickly, I’d definitely recommend **Expo**

Note: This answer is a blend from multiple developers